# error running tensorflow trained model c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am working on Tensorflow on c++ with network I trained myself. I trained facenet on MS-Celeb-1M then I created my graph.pb. I modified the example provided here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image in order to test my network.

In main.cpp:

```
string graph = "data/graph1.pb";
string output_layer = "InceptionResnetV1/Repeat/block35_5/Relu";
```

I get this error if I test :

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'phase_train' with dtype bool [[Node: phase_train = Placeholderdtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0 /cpu:0"]]
```

I have looked for some answers such as here https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/issues/108:

> But there is still a problem
>
> ```
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'phase_train' with dtype bool
> ```
>
> when global variables are initialized. I'm not sure why this problem happens but it has to do with batch normalization. It can be fixed by changing
>
> ```
> phase_train_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> phase_train_placeholder = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.convert_to_tensor(True, dtype=tf.bool), shape=(), name='phase_train')
> ```
>
> And then it seems to work fine.

David Sandberg is speaking about changing a line. However, I don't know how can I provide the parameter `phase_train` in c++.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Session->Run, the first input to the method is a vector of pair. You need to create a tensor with the name phase_train, type Boolean, and a value of whatever makes sense. Add that tensor to the input list.